# The program cannot find correct version of glibc/libstdc++, although it was statically linked

Tags: gcc, g++, ld, glibc, libstdc++

I am trying to link my program statically with glibc, because version of the glibc on the target machine is pretty much unpredictable. I used linker flags -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ and it worked fine. The executable is big, but I can live with it. Unfortunately, when I run my executable on the target machine (it is named 'mytest' in the example below) I get the following error:

```
./mytest: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by libboost_log.so.1.53.0)
./mytest: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by libboost_log.so.1.53.0)
./mytest: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by libboost_log.so.1.53.0)
./mytest: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by libboost_date_time.so.1.53.0)
./mytest: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by libboost_thread.so.1.53.0)
```

If I do 'strings' on mytest, it gives me

```
$ strings mytest | grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4
```

What means, I think, that the static linking was working ok. Why does the loader still tries to look for my functions in shared glibc and libstdc++? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to link my program statically with glibc, because version of the glibc on the target machine is pretty much unpredictable. I used linker flags -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ and it worked fine.

That didn't affect the version of glibc (`libc`), which is *different* from `libgcc` and `libstdc++`. With these flags, you still have produced a dynamically-linked executable, which is *expected* to not work on an older distribution.

You can link your executable with `-static` flag, and that should give you a *completely* static executable.

**Update:**

After re-reading your question; your problem is *not* with `glibc`. Your problem is that you are linking with `libboost_log.so`, which itself depends on `libstdc++.so.6`.

The answer then is to link with `libboost*.a` instead of `libboost*.so`. You can try to achieve it this way:

```
g++ $(OBJS) -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_log ... \
  -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

(It is *very* important to have the trailing `-Wl,-Bdynamic`.)

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunately, I cannot link everything statically, because then my pthread library is not working. For whatever reason, it works ok only if it linked dynamically.

Comment: @svetlana `libpthread` is part of glibc. If you can't link it statically, then you can't have a fully static executable, and that implies that your executable will *never* work on an older system (that's just not supported). Static linking *does* work for multithreaded programs in general, so you need to either figure out why it isn't working for your particular case, or give up on the whole idea.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting. I've never used -B flags, but it might work. Thank you again :)

Comment: Ok, I've tried your suggestion. Now I get ./mytest: symbol lookup error: /home/sveta/mytest/lib/libstdc++.so.6: undefined symbol: _ZGVNSt8numpunctIcE2idE, version GLIBCXX_3.4 IF I try readelf -Ws mytest, I can see the symbol. Needless to say, it is present in the libstdc++.so.6. I'm lost... Back to the original question: why it doesn't use static version from the executable???

Answer (score 1):

Linking with `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` will only work for those libraries.  It looks like you are also linking against the boost libraries (likely dynamically) which then link against libgcc and libstdc++.

Try running the following:

```
ldd mytest
```

It should show "not a dynamic executable".  If it shows anything else, it means it is dynamically linked against other libraries.  It doesn't always work so easily, but try adding `-static` to the compilation line as well to take care of remaining libraries.