# Run c scrips from a shell script

Tags: c++, c, shell, csh

I have this shell script

```
#!/bin/csh
@ x = 1
while ($x <= 2)
nohup ./prog1 && ./prog2 &
@ x ++
end
```

I want to run sequentially for 2 times prog1 and prog2 that are previously compiled trough a makefile. How can I do it? Is the script right?

If I do

```
chmod u+x test.csh
./test.csh
```

I get this error

```
./prog1: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./prog1)
```

This is my makefile

```
GSLFLAGS := `pkg-config --cflags gsl`  
LIBGSL := `pkg-config --libs gsl`
CFLAGS = -O3 -fopenmp
LIBOMP = -lgomp

dist.o:dist.cxx
    g++ -Wall -c dist.cxx

prog1.o:prog1.cxx
    g++ -Wall -c prog1.cxx  $< ${GSLFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}

prog1:prog1.o dist.o 
    g++ ${CFLAGS} -o  $@ $^ ${LIBGSL} 

prog2.o:prog2.cxx
    g++ -Wall -c prog2.cxx  $< ${GSLFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}

prog2:prog2.o dist.o 
    g++ ${CFLAGS} -o  $@ $^ ${LIBGSL}
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `./prog1` from the shell?

Comment: It works fine, that's the strange part

Comment: Is your normal shell `/bin/csh` ?
Also, does running `nohup ./prog1` from the command line work as well?

Comment: Yes nohup ./prog1 work as well

Comment: I recommend you run "set | grep -i LIB" in your normal shell, and then put the same command as the second line of your script above. Then look at the differences and see what is missing when running in your script then correct your library search path for the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the search path for the standard C++ library is set differently in csh vs. when you run from the command line.

[Linking the standard libraries statically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16249176/335858) should make the library search path irrelevant: change your makefile as follows:

```
CFLAGS = -O3 -fopenmp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Comment: But how the while works? It seem to me that it is running in parallel prog1 and prog2 two times and not prog1 prog2 prog1 prog2

Comment: @user3036416 Isn't that the effect that you are looking for? Your script tells `nohup` to put programs in the background, because you put an ampersand `&` at the end. If you are looking to run them sequentially, remove the ampersand. Better yet, "unroll" the loop (i.e. "spell out" its actions one by one, the way the other answer suggests), because your loop is very short.

Comment: I removed the & at the end and now it is fine! Thanks

Comment: Please be aware, OP, that this is a sort of sticking plaster. The problem is actually that your library search path is different in your two shells. If you link statically, as suggested here, your binary will be bigger as it will include all the library code that is normally shared between binaries - so it will take longer to load and drain your system resources more. There are other downsides to static linking too, so please consider whether you really want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do what you ask, use this:

```
#!/bin/csh
./prog1
./prog2
./prog1
./prog2
```

I sense you are confused by backgrounding process and the like.

Run prog1 then prog2 if prog1 exits successfully:

```
./prog1 && ./prog2
```

Run prog1 and then prog2 regardless:

```
./prog1; ./prog2
```

Run prog1 in the background:

```
./prog1 &
```

Sleep 8 seconds then ring bell, but give me back my prompt immediately:

```
(sleep 3; sleep 5;echo $'\a') &
```

Comment: And what if I have a lot of iterations?

Comment: You said you have two.